# Lambda no se ejecuta desde una lista expandible

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Buen dia,

El caso es que, tengo un adaptador que genera una lista desplegable, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando no haya nada en la lista desplegable se muestre de forma centrada una imagen que indique que no hay datos para mostrar.

El problema es que tengo una lambda para hacer visible la imagen desde el Main Activity pero no hace nada, tengo implemendatas otras lambdas con recyclerview en otras clases y funciona bien, quise replicarlo y no hace nada, ni me muestra un error. Tienen alguna idea de que pueda estar fallando?, o si saben alguna otra forma para hacerlo, su apoyo para orientarme.

Gracias por su atencion.

**Adaptador:**

```
      class adaptador_expandiblelist internal constructor(val context:Context, val lista_clientes:MutableList<Data_entregas>, val lista_productos:HashMap<Data_entregas,MutableList<Data_entregas>>/):
            BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
        
        override fun getGroupCount(): Intoverride fun getGroupCount(): Int{...}
        override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int{...}
        override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Data_entregas{...}
        override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Data_entregas{...} 
        override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {...}
        override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {...}
        override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean{...}
        override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int, isexpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View{...}
        override fun isChildSelectable(p0: Int, p1: Int): Boolean {...}
        
     
        override fun getChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLasrChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
           // Aqui llamo a la funcion del Main Activity
            btn_eliminar.setOnClickListener(){
                muestra_imagen?.invoke()
            }

        }
        var muestra_imagen:(()->Unit)?=null
        fun ejecu_img(callback: ()->Unit){
           this.muestra_imagen=callback
        }
```

**Main Activity**

```
class Ventana2 : AppCompatActivity(), Serializable{
 var adapta:adaptador_expandiblelist?=null
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ventana2)

           adapta?.ejecu_img{
            var Texto:ImageView=findViewById(R.id.textView34)   
            Texto!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
}
```

Comment: textView34 se tiene en activity_ventana2.xml ?

Comment: Si, en el XML activity_ventana2 se encuentra la imagen.